# Vuex Classic mode for store/ is deprecated and will be removed in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have below files and could not find the reason for warning "Classic mode for store/ is deprecated and will be removed in Nuxt 3". Everything works fine just getting that annoying warning.

***modules/data.js*** file in store of nuxt.js.

```
    const state = () => ({
      loadedPosts: []
    });

    const mutations = {
      setPosts(state, posts){
        state.loadedPosts = posts;
      }
    };

    const actions = {
      setPosts(vuexContext, posts){
        vuexContext.commit('setPosts', posts);
      }
    };

    const getters = {
      loadedPosts(state){
        return state.loadedPosts;
      }
    };

    export default {
      state,
      actions,
      getters,
      mutations
    };
```

***index.js*** file in store of nuxt.js.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import data from "~/store/modules/data";

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      data: {
        namespaced: true,
        ...data
      }
    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally, after reading a lot of answers and blogs I figured out the solution.

**Important:-** Forgot what you know about vuex module in vue.js app. Using Vuex in nuxt.js is a bit different.

**Solution:-** Nuxt.js lets you have a **store** directory with every file corresponding to a module. Just add necessary files in the ***store*** directly you don't need to create and add files to '**modules**' directory in store. **index.js** file is a special file and this is where we would put the logic that is not related to a module.

**store/data.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  loadedPosts: []
});

export const mutations = {
  setPosts(state, posts){
    state.loadedPosts = posts;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  setPosts(vuexContext, posts){
    vuexContext.commit('setPosts', posts);
  }
};

export const getters = {
  loadedPosts(state){
    return state.loadedPosts;
  }
};
```

Using **state** in project

```
this.$store.data.loadedPosts
```

Using **mutations** in project

```
this.$store.commit('data/setPosts', [{id: '1',...}, {id: '2',...}]);
```

Using **actions** in project

```
this.$store.dispatch('data/setPosts', [{id: '1',...}, {id: '2',...}]);
```

Using **getters** in project

```
this.$store.getters['data/loadedPosts'];
```

**Important References:-**

1. Watch this video [Nuxt.js tutorial for beginners - nuxt.js vuex store](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_ShKJ7PJ3U)
2. Read this blog [Efficiently understanding and using Nuxt + Vuex](https://itnext.io/efficiently-understanding-and-using-nuxt-vuex-7905eb8858d6)

Comment: `...getters['data/loadedPosts']` / `...dispatch('data/setPosts')` - Mr.Stark I am not feeling well..

I mean seriouslly this is an awfull syntax.. But you're 100% right that's the new deal with nuxt, big mistake..

Comment: another way is to create `store/data/[actions.js, getters.js, mutations.js, state.js]`, so nuxt will use "data" folder as a module.

Comment: Just can't need create index.js

Answer (score 0):

If it seems to you that everything has been done as per Nuxt docs but you still see the «Classic mode is deprecated» warning, the following may help:

1. Go to the directory where the built files are, i.e. `dist`
2. Open store.js
3. See the following piece of code:

```
if (typeof store === 'function') {
    return console.warn('Classic mode for store/ is deprecated and will be removed in Nuxt 3.')
}
```

4. Check what is being exported from your store/index.?s — is it a function? That's where the warning comes from. Fix it by exporting an object.

Answer (score -2):

Nuxt display this warning because you use a classic vuex store, not a « modules mode ». You can learn more about in [nuxt doc](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode).